# Android DataBinding & MVVM - Using same name for layout files in different layout folders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

I've been developing an app with data binding & MVVM.

I'm trying to use an alternative layout for my app on landscape mode. I have:

```
layout/fragment_content.xml
layout-land/fragment_content.xml
```

Both layouts have same views with different look, and get feeds from same view models, like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data class="MyBinding">

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.myapp.package.viewModel.VMFirst"/>

    <variable
        name="controlModel"
        type="com.myapp.package.viewModel.VMSecond"/>
</data>

<DIFFERENT CONTENT HERE>
```

All the views and id's exist in both layouts.

Well, problem is, it doesn't compile, error is simply `"cannot find symbol method getViewModel"` and getter for the other variable.

What I tried so far:

1. Using layout and layout-land folders ( Failed, error is explained above )
2. Using layout aliases [Use Layout Aliases](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) which I found here [Issue 199344: Data binding does not work with layout aliases](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199344). I didn't change anything in xml files while trying this approach. This also failed, error is `Could not write to com.myapp.package.databinding.MyBinding`

Is it not possible to use data binding `data` tag in multiple layout files ? What should I use to use different layouts for different states while using data binding ? Thanks !

Edit: deleting `class="MyBinding"` did not change errors.

Comment: Can you post your `VMFirst` or your `VMSecond` class?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem. I have a standard layout file and a sw720dp file and I get the exact problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a third layout file like `base_data_xyz` containing the `<data>` but no views, then `<include>` it in both layouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone searches for this question, after 2 years I tried to do the same, and I saw it's working all fine now.

I created a layout file `activity_main` under `layout` and `layout_sw600dp`. Here's the layout under `layout` resources:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <variable
        name="small_variable"
        type="Integer"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/myRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/small_square"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This one is the layout under `layout_sw600dp` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <variable
        name="big_variable"
        type="Long"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/myRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/big_square"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Both has a view but it has different id in each: `small_square` and `big_square`.

I run the project on phone & tablet. Here are my findings:

- DataBinding creates an implementation that contains **ALL** views and variables under all layout files of same name in different layout folders.
- Views that exists in all layouts are not nullable, all others are nullable. In above XML's, `myRoot` is **not a nullable view** when using binding from Kotlin, while `big_square` and `small_square` **are nullable** views. Variables are nullable whether or not they exists in all layouts ( which is expected behaviour ).
- You cannot name binding classes different in each file. It has to be same ( `MainBinding` in above examples, or if you don't define it `LayoutResourceName` + `Binding` by default ).
- Names for views and variables on binding implementation are camel case. So my `small_variable` & `small_square` was `binding.smallVariable` and `binding.smallSquare` on code side.
- With Kotlin, you can just use views like `binding.bigSquare?.operation`, which is great that you don't need to check if it's tablet or phone or view is null or not beforehand.
- Just a tip, you can assign `binding` fields even if layout that they are in won't be used. You can still say `binding.smallVariable = 3` on code and it'll do the assignment and save the value. I think it's good to be careful.

Comment: Thanks for this insight!

Answer (score 2):

I heavily use MVVM in my apps and am also building a library around it.

I follow the convention that there is a single ViewModel in every XML. Also, the name of the viewmodel variable is same in all XMLs.

So, in your case, you can create another ViewModel class that contains `VMFirst` and `VMSecond`.

```
public class ParentVM {
   VMFirst first;
   VMSecond second;
}
```

Both the XMLs (portrait and landscape) will have same names, say `activity_main.xml`.

```
<layout>
    <data>
      <variable 
          type="ParentViewModel"
          name="vm"/>
    </data>
```

Then no check is required in MainActivity code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setVariable(BR.vm, new ParentViewModel());
}
```

This works.

## Advantages of single ViewModel

In fact, because I follow same variable name throughout all xmls, I am able to include the binding logic in a base class `MvvmActivity` itself. So, all my activities look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends MvvmActivity {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ViewModel createViewModel() {
        return new MainViewModel();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```

MvvmActivity implementation: [MvvmActivity.java](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm/blob/master/android-mvvm/src/main/java/com/manaschaudhari/android_mvvm/MvvmActivity.java)

Another advantage of keeping a constant data binding variable is that you can setup RecyclerView or ViewPager adapters in XML itself. See [Setup RecyclerView from XML](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm#data-binding-to-reduce-boilerplate) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing "Binding" to it. The above layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class was MainActivityBinding. --[Binding Data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data)

and generated at compile time.

so, select different layout by java code.

```
layout/
R.layout.activity_main
R.layout.activity_main_tablet

values/
    <bool name="is_mobile">true</bool>
    <bool name="is_tablet">false</bool>
values-w820dp/
    <bool name="is_mobile">false</bool>
    <bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_mobile)) {
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);            
    } else {
        ActivityMainTabletBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main_tablet);   
    }

}
```

Comment: True, but what I seek is the correct way of using data binding with different layout varieties for same view. As far as I tried changing binding name does not solve this error. Approach that same page suggests ( layout aliases) also not working. I don't see the point of using different layouts if I'll check the device size and inflate with an  if / else block. Do you know / came across any working code examples for this ?