# Android recyclerview data-binding different layout for screen size

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that use data binding library with a recyclerview. The problem that I'm facing is how to use a different layout when the screen is rotated. Normally, without data-binding, what I usually do is create a second layout (with the same name) for the single item of the recyclerview in the folder layout-land, but with data-binding I obtain an error when building the project (the corrisponding databinding class for the layout is not generated).
Is there a way to use data-binding in this situation?
Thanks

**Edit** this is the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.eloquentbit.moovist.viewmodel.ItemMovieViewModel" />
    </data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        fresco:roundedCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.posterImageUrl}"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_original_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@{viewModel.originalTitle}"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Doctor Strange"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_overview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_original_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text_original_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text_original_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_half"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:text="@{viewModel.overview}"
        tools:text="Overview"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**Edit 2** This is the github repo: [Moovist](https://github.com/eloquentbit/Moovist/tree/mvvm)

**Edit 3** I try to better explain the problem: when I make the second layout in the layout-land folder, with the same name of the portrait layout (item_movie.xml), I obtain an error message during compilation task:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getViewModel()
```

and the corrisponding databinding class (ItemMovieBinding) is not created.

**getViewModel** is a method in my RecyclerView adapter class:

```
package com.eloquentbit.moovist.adapter;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.eloquentbit.moovist.R;
import com.eloquentbit.moovist.databinding.ItemMovieBinding;
import com.eloquentbit.moovist.model.Movie;
import com.eloquentbit.moovist.viewmodel.ItemMovieViewModel;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public MovieAdapter() {
        this.movies = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemMovieBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.item_movie,
                parent,
                false);

        return new MovieViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindMovie(movies.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ItemMovieBinding binding;

        public MovieViewHolder(ItemMovieBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void bindMovie(Movie movie) {
            if (binding.getViewModel() == null) {
                binding.setViewModel(new ItemMovieViewModel(itemView.getContext(), movie));
            } else {
                binding.getViewModel().setMovie(movie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 4**: I've found that this is actually a bug; using version 2.3-alpha1 of android gradle plugin I can use the two layout without any problem. For more information see this: [Issue 199344](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199344)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364813/android-databinding-mvvm-using-same-layout-files-for-different-conditions-us

Comment: Thanks Ishita, I've already seen that post, but I think is a bit different with a recyclerview.

Comment: Can you please share your layout file for recyclerview item?

Comment: Hi Ravi, I've added the layout